# no suitable constructor exists to convert from "uint8_t *" to "std::vector<uint8_t, std::allocator<uint8_t>>"

Tags: c++

```
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "uint8_t *" to "std::vector<uint8_t, std::allocator<uint8_t>>"
```

and the cast not working

Edit:

```
const std::vector<uint8_t> Test (const std::vector<uint8_t> buffer) const;

uint8_t* buffer="...";

//so i can use Test() function
Test(buffer);

Error
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "uint8_t *" to "std::vector<uint8_t, std::allocator<uint8_t>>"
```

Comment: You need to clarify a bit, perhaps with some code, what you're trying to do. This just tells me you have an `uint8_t` pointer that you're casting to a STL `vector`. How would the vector type know the length of the integer sequence you're giving it?

Comment: You should really know by now how to ask a real question … >:-(

Comment: @Shtééf- Edit; @Konrad Rudolph- dont be mad man xD , i just though maybe my prob faced someone before so i didnt post a code !_! well i edit it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot convert an `array` to a `std::vector`, you need to construct one explicitly.
One way to do it would be to use the `vector`'s range constructor like this:

```
uint8_t* buffer="...";
// +1 for the terminating \0
std::vector<uint8_t> vector( buffer, buffer + strlen( buffer ) + 1 ); 
Test( vector );
```

---

As a side note if your buffer has embedded `\0` then `strlen` will return an incorrect value. As a workaround you can do something like this:

```
uint8_t[] buffer="...";
std::vector<uint8_t> vector( buffer, buffer + sizeof( buffer ) ); 
Test( vector );
```